# VBCodeProvider Error - error BC2006: option 'r' requires':<file_list>'

Tags: .net, codedom

I am trying to use the VBCodeProvider to dynamically compile an assembly. The problem I'm running in to is that I need to give the CompilerParameters class a list of referenced assemblies.

The code being used is this:

```
CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Select(a => a.Location).ToArray());
parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
parameters.IncludeDebugInformation = false;

CodeDomProvider provider = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider();

// Compile the assembly in memory.
CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parameters, compileUnit);
```

The problem is that when the `provider.CompileAssemblyFromDom` line runs, it generates the following error:

`vbc : Command line (0,0) : error BC2006: option 'r' requires':<file_list>'`

However, if I use the CSharpCodeProvider

`provider = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.CSharpCodeProvider();`

everything works correctly.

Is this a known bug in the `VBCodeProvider`?

Comment: Please post code that compiles.  Your AddRange() call is bad.  I cannot otherwise repro your problem.

Comment: nobugz: Updated the code, left of a .ToArray() on the end.